# How can I develop an appropriate circular arc connecting two points?

Tags: geometry

I need to draw a suitable arc connecting the location $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$; before $(x_1,y_1)$ there is a surface developed which is a polynomial curve, and $(x_2,y_2)$ is the point of tangency at the end for a given circle radius, which is known to me.

The arc should be such that the surface remains smooth at the connecting points and the tangency condition is satisfied at the end. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can't impose two endpoints and two directions.

Comment: Please provide a figure.